# POST Params aren't passed to controller on API Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rest, curl

When I post to my resource via CURL in my Rails 3 application then the parameters aren't passed all the way to the controller.

So when I post `{"favorite_user": {"username": "someuser"}}` I end up with the following params:

```
{"format"=>:json, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"v1/favorite_users"}
```

This is my POST Request:

```
POST /api/favorite_users HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
Host: myapp.com
Content-Type: application/myapp.com; version=1
Accept: application/myapp.com; version=1
Content-Length: 48

{"favorite_user": {"username": "someuser"}}
```

My routes.rb:

```
scope 'api', as: 'api' do
  api_version(module: 'V1',
              header: {name: 'Accept', value: 'application/myapp.com; version=1'},
              defaults: {format: :json}) do
    resources :favorite_users, only: [:index, :show, :create]
  end
end
```

`rake routes` yields this:

```
api_favorite_users GET    /api/favorite_users(.:format)                                        V1/favorite_users#index {:format=>:json}
                   POST   /api/favorite_users(.:format)                                        V1/favorite_users#create {:format=>:json}
 api_favorite_user GET    /api/favorite_users/:id(.:format)                                    V1/favorite_users#show {:format=>:json}
```

My controller:

```
class V1::FavoriteUsersController < V1::BaseController

  # ...

  def create
    render text: params.to_s
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the Versionist gem for versioning your API, you need to change the `Content-Type` header to something that Rails will understand.  Your data is JSON, so the header should be `Content-Type: application/json`.  Versionist doesn't tell Rails how to interpret and decode incoming request bodies with the custom `Content-Type`, it only looks at the `Accept` header value for a matching type.